# I cannot get data to reset when closing a modal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a modal which takes data from a parent component as a prop.
Inside the modal there are multiple components containing form fields. These use the same prop which is passed on from the modal.

First I have the parent component, where I fetch data with axios in an external js file and pass the data into an object called "user". I then pass this data in the ref for my child-modal:

```
<template>
  <b-container

  <b-card-group deck class="mb-4">
    <b-card
      :bg-variant="getStatusClass(user.status)"
      text-variant="white" class="action-card"
      @click="$refs.changeStatusModal.show(user)">
      <b-card-title>
        <h3>User status</h3>
      </b-card-title>
      <b-card-text>
        <span v-if="user.registrationDate">{{ $d(new Date(user.registrationDate)) }}</span> -
      </b-card-text>
    </b-card>
    
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
    data() {
      return {
        user: {
          parentId: null,
        },
      };
    },
    methods: {
      load() {
        axiosService.get(this.$route.params.id).then(result => {
          this.user = result.data;
          this.setUser(this.user);
          if (this.user.parentId) {
            tenancyService.get(this.user.parentId).then(result => {
              this.parent = result.data;
            });
          }
      },
    }
</script>
```

As for the modal: It contains dates and status for a user. There are two buttons. One which saves any changes made inside a current status, and a button which changes the user status to the next level. Eg. user.status.new -> user.status.warningSent. The user data is passed as a prop to the components contained inside this modal

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    v-model="open"
    size="lg"
    :title="changeModalTitle"
    :header-bg-variant="changeModalHeaderBgColor"
    :header-text-variant="changeModalTextColor"
    body-class="position-static">
    

    <user-status-new :user="user" />
    <user-status-warning-sent :user="user" />
    <user-status-blocked :user="user" />
    <user-status-deleted :user="user" />

  
    <template #modal-footer>
      <div>
        <b-button variant="primary" :@click="submit">{{ $t('save') }}</b-button>
        <b-button variant="warning" @click="nextStatus">{{ $t('changeStatus') }}<i class="fas fa-arrow-right ml-2"></i></b-button>
      </div>
    </template>
    
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
    data() {
      return {
        modalTitle: null,
        headerBgVariant: null,
        headerTextVariant: 'dark',
        user: {
          status: null,
          registrationDate: null,
          dateOfBlocking: null,
          dateOfTermination: null,

        },
        open: false,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      show(user) {
        this.user.$reset();
        Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.apply(this));
        this.user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
        user.registrationDate = user.registrationDate ? new Date(user.registrationDate) : user.registrationDate;
        user.dateOfTermination = user.dateOfTermination ? new Date(user.dateOfTermination) : user.dateOfTermination;

        this.user = user

        this.open = true;
      },
    }
</script>
```

As for the individual components inside the modal, they just contain bootstrap form fields which hold the data:

```
      <b-col lg="6">
        <b-form-group :label="$t('registrationDate')">
          <b-date-picker v-model="user.registrationDate" />
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
```

As you can see, I have used $reset() as well as Object.assign, which SHOULD reset the data whenever the modal is loaded again if a user has entered new dates without saving them, but this is not what happens. If I close the modal and open it again, the changed dates will still appear and they will not go away unless I reload the whole page.

I tried different variations, this.user.registrationDate.$reset(); But it does not work. I have also tried to create a test button that ran a method where if "open" was false, then it should do a reset. Didn't work either. I CAN make a method that sets the data to null, but I don't want that, because there might actually be some existing dates that has been entered earlier, so I would like the modal to default back to those (saved) dates until a new save is made.